# How to initialize inherited contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts

I find there is a contract named `ERC20Capped` inherited from `ERC20Mintable` in [zippelin contract project](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Capped.sol).

Both of them have their own construction parameters.How to assign value to them during contract deployment using `web3` api?

meanwhile, I generete web3 deployment code using remix, however, there is no parameters setting, like below:

```
var erc20mintableContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"sender","type":"address"},{"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"addMinter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"renounceMinter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"isMinter","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"MinterAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"MinterRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]);
var erc20mintable = erc20mintableContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add them inside `[]` immediate after the `new(`.

Comment: BTW, `ERC20Mintable` doesn't "have its own construction parameters"!

Comment: Thanks! After modify .sol source code and add construction function it works.But when I try to mint coin by execuate "var mintflag = await contract.methods.mint(myAddress,10000).call();", I got an error message which says "TypeError: contract.methods.mint is not a function ", I can not understand what happen after check the code,please help.thanks again!

Comment: `console.log(contract.methods)` please.

Comment: I find the reason that I use wrong abi.json file and now it's correct.besides, I found `console.log(contract.methods)` can not print ERC20 function and self-defined function(e.g. mint(a,b)).Just basic functions are listed.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract that inherits from ERC20Capped can either set the cap in your constructor or can pass on a constructor parameter.  ERC20Mintable doesn't have any constructor parameters.

Example token with the cap specified in the constructor:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Capped.sol";

contract CappedToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed, ERC20Capped {

    constructor () 
        ERC20Detailed("Capped Token", "TKN", 18) 
        ERC20Capped(1000000 * (10 ** 18))
        public
    {

    }
}
```

The OpenZeppelin Contracts documentation has information on the ERC20 implementation and associated contracts: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC20

You can also ask questions about using OpenZeppelin on the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin